# Why suddenly my .zshrc file color is different from other files?

Tags: oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Last thing I remember editing in my .zshrc file, is adding java path, for use with appium.

Four days ago I started to see my .zshrc file formerly white, showing in red color when "ls-al"
(I have oh-my-zsh installed, default theme, so, red or green colors might not be a good reference)

Also when I attempt to autocomplete (vim .zsh + TAB) the options show my .zshrc file in green and with an asterisk at the end!

I'm still able to make app builds and all other daily work in the terminal, no issues or blockers, but the colors are weird. Do you guys know what might be happening?

I added image of ls-al and vim .zsh + TAB

[.zshrc_different_colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1IdM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green color with the asterisk mean that the `.zshrc` file has been made executable. That's what all the `x`'s stand for on the left side of the screen in `-rwxr-xr-x@`. The red color could mean there is a dangling symlink. The @ symbol could mean the file has extended attributes.